# Do global logging settings in MySQL5 stick after service restart?

Tags: linux, mysql, redhat, mysql5

Want to execute this on MySQL 5.0:

> set global log_warnings = 2;

Will the setting stick after a mysqld service restart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Variable could be enabled in option file my.cnf, otherwise after restart it will be reset to default value `1`

Comment: Ok so if I do it my way, it will start logging aborted connections right after execution?

Comment: @blizz [Not in 5.0 or 5.1.   There's a bug regarding aborted connections](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19285/log-warnings-doesnt-seem-to-work-for-aborted-connections-in-mysql-5-1).  Should work in 5.5 and later but even that's not certain.

Comment: oh well that's confusing...so I can't log aborted connections in 5.0 except in the general query log? Would I enable it the same way, or do I need to set it in my.cnf and restart the service?

Comment: Simply do both.